# Firebase AdMob implementation crashing app

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

I am using Google Firebase for analytics, crash reporting, authentication...

I installed SDKs with Cocoa Pods. All currently installed SDKs work fine.

After adding AdMob SDK my app crashes. Right after successful build I get different errors on different devices.

Iphone 6s:

`-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
 `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000000062662'`

And iPad 2:

`-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6100000348a0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000024dc0'`

I am not even initialising AdMob in AppDelegate class, just implementing it and trying to build.

If I remove AdMob from project, app works fine so its definitely AdMob problem.

I really cant find any useful help or someone with similar problem. Creating new and clean project definitely wont be my solution.
 I guess there is something wrong with my project configuration, because in my other project I have implemented AdMob about month ago and everything works fine.

Comment: update your question with admob code written

Comment: i have written that i havent added any of code. Just implementing sdk.